# Why a group $G$ can form a 2-category?

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, higher-category-theory

I know (and understand) how a single group can form a category (of one object, morphisms are the action of the group elements as endomorphisms on it). However here [Describing the Wreath product categorically.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867203/describing-the-wreath-product-categorically?rq=1), Qiaochu Yuan states that moreover a group $G$ forms a 2-category, which seems to be quite interesting but lacks of an explanation on the internet unfortunately. Can you please explain which the 2-morphisms are in that case? Also if someone knows, can you write some of the applications of this 2-category?

Comment: What I mean is that the whole collection of groups forms a 2-category, not an individual group. This 2-category shows up in algebraic topology and is a conceptual way of understanding the classification of group extensions.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your reply! Oh, I see! So I totally misunderstood what you wrote out. So I rephrase, how the category of groups becomes a 2-category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to understand how the category of groups becomes a 2-category, and in general if you want to understand 2-categories, you ought to be familiar with the canonical example of a (strict) 2-category, namely **Cat** itself. This the the category of all (small) categories, and has as its objects categories, as its morphisms functors, and as its 2-morphisms natural transformations. Taking a group to be a category with one object, **Grp** becomes a full subcategory of **Cat**. Ultimately, I would recommend that you try to spend some more time understanding all these definitions, as once you have that set, the 2-category structure of **Grp** will become pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you know if there is any kind of embedding of an arbitrary 2-category in **Cat**?

Comment: also do you have a kind of textbook or notes for these things?

Comment: I highly doubt it. **Grp** is a subcategory of **Cat** because it's defined that way. It's not like **Cat** is necessarily the end-all-be-all of 2-categories.

Comment: Regarding 2-categories, and more generally higher categories, I don't know of any good references; I've only picked them up off of resources scattered across the Internet. For ordinary category theory, I've picked up *Topos Theory: The Categorial Analysis of Logic*, by Robert Goldblatt, which starts out with a gentle introduction to Category Theory before it goes into the more foundational material. I think it does a good job of providing some decent motivation for the material, which can otherwise be difficult to get a grip on, what with all the abstract nonsense floating around.

Comment: Another good book seems to be *Category Theory in Context*, by Emily Riehl. I haven't read it thoroughly; it seems a bit more advanced in its strictly category-theoretic development, however it still aims to present category theory to the novice. Both books are very inexpensive - about $20 on Amazon. They are Dover books after all.

Comment: I don't think there are any textbook treatments of 2-categories, but Steve Lack's paper "A 2-Categories Companion", available at his website, is a great introduction. By the way, on your embedding question: the analogies question for categories is whether every category embeds into Set, which is false.